# What does "Every me, every you" mean?

Tags: american-english

What does one mean when he says "Every me, every you"?

Comment: Welcome to the site, luckyduck. I'm sorry to inform you that this question is off-topic as per FAQ - song lyrics explanations do not belong to this site. If you want your question answered, remove the song references like "In the song ..." and keep the grammar only.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't knew that. Removed all song references.

Comment: You're giving unhelpful advice Rimmer. Without the reference to song lyrics, the answer to the question is "No idea, it's not a meaningful English phrase". Once you know it is poetry, you can guess what it might mean (though you'd really need some context) but it is off-topic for this site whether the question says songs or not.

Comment: @ColinFine, all I meant is to remove the binding, limiting it to songs only. If the phrase means nothing outside of poetry, then vote to close as not a real question or whatnot.

Comment: I voted to close when the song references were at stake, but now as the question is edited, I don't see it as off-topic anymore, therefore my close vote is invalid, although I don't know how to un-vote it.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to determine what might one mean by the phrase as it's provided out of context, leaving the reader understand it completely by their own imagination.

There are a few options, though.

Option 1, literal: In a science-fiction work/world, for example when time travel is at hand, there literally may be more "copies" of a certain person, therefore one could say:

> We need to find every me and every you to end this mess once and for all.

Option 2, poetic: By saying "every me" one may imply "every part of me", meaning "completely me, all of me, whole me as I am." Therefore the phrase may mean:

> Every me and every you, we both completely as we are.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Referencing the original context is the poetic one, talking about love and feelings. Therefor I guess the Option 2 is right. Thanks once again!